# Use Raspberry Pi as wifi bridge multiple interfaces

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet

I am building something that needs an ethernet connect and i want to use my raspberry pi 4 to take my wifi signal and convert it to ethernet. This has been done before but what has not been done is use 2 external wifi interfaces connected to eachother to make it faster. In Windows its possible under Network Indexes but how do i do it for my Pi?

Thanks

Comment: You can't do bridges with WiFi, it's disallowed.

Comment: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-wifi-bridge/

Comment: That's not a bridge.